# How to set values on components of a primitive that's part of a primitive I am registering in aframe?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I am registering a primitive in frame that is composed of other primitives. But I want to scale and position these inner primitives independently. But as position itself is a component, these inner primitives do not have a position and therefore i cannot move them around.

How can I set values on components of a primitive thats part of a primitive I want to register?

```js
AFRAME.registerPrimitive('a-svrbutton', {
  defaultComponents: {
    geometry: {
      primitive: 'box',
      height: 1.5,
      depth: 0.2,
      width: 3.5
    },
    material: {
      opacity: 1.0,
      transparent: true,
      side: 'Double',
      color: '#8450ff'
    },
    position: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: -5
    },
    'bmfont-text': {
      text: 'hola',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },

  },
  mappings: {
    height: 'geometry.height',
    width: 'geometry.width',
    depth: 'geometry.depth',
    color: 'material.color',
    opacity: 'material.opacity',
    position: 'position'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

<a-scene>
  <a-svrbutton id="mybutton" position="0 0 -5"></a-svrbutton>
</a-scene>
```

<sup>Make sure that your browser supports WebVR to run snippet above.</sup>

I want to define as default position in the default "components" bmfont-text as an arbitrary x y and z. But I can't because this 'primitive' does not have a position component itself. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you include sample code for what you've tried so far? There are different ways to set up the bmfont, and I don't know what other primitives (maybe you mean components?) are involved. You can put position onto any element, even if it's a primitive that's doesn't affect position.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to know if this is related to templating, or with components + primitives.

Answer (score 2):

A [primitive](https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/primitives/) is usually a shorthand for one or more *components*, not other primitives, so I may be misunderstanding what you're doing – if so could you add sample code to your question?

You can generally add unrelated components to a primitive just fine, even if the primitive doesn't have that component already:

```
<a-text text="Hello World;" position="0 0 -5"></a-text>
```

If that's not working, I'd suggest using bmfont as a component rather than the `<a-text />` primitive version.

```
<a-entity bmfont-text="text: Hello World;" position="0 0 -5"></a-entity>
```

As of A-Frame v0.3.0 there are some [bugs with primitives](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1900), so components and mixins may be more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to make them two separate entities.

```
<a-entity>
  <a-srvbutton></a-srvbutton>
  <a-text></a-text>
</a-entity>
```

Or perhaps make a wrapper component to wrap the bmfont text?

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('bmfont-text-wrapper', {
  schema: {
    textPosition: {type: 'vec3'},
    text: {type: 'string'}
  },

  init: function () {
    var text = document.createElement('a-entity');
    text.setAttribute('bmfont-text', this.data.text);
    text.setAttribute('position', this.data.textPosition);
    this.el.appendChild(text);
  }
});
```

And then add the mappings.